# Open ffplay & execute command with ProcessBuilder not working

Tags: java, cmd, ffmpeg

I was tried to use ProcessBuilder for open ffplay.exe and execute command into ffplay. However it is unsuccessful. How could I do that?

**Code:**

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

pb.command("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c",
"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffplay.exe", "tcp://192.168.1.1:5555"); 

pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and doing like this :-

```
String[] command = {"ffplay.exe", "tcp://192.168.1.1:5555"}; // add in String array in sequence, the commands to execute
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] options, null, new File("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin"));
int returnVal = process.waitFor(); // should return 0 for correct execution
try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //check for the inputstream & see the output here
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hi there, may I know how to add add in array in sequence to execute? Thanks!

Comment: @DennisQT what i meant was to add the complete command in `String` array separated by whitespace. like if command is `ffmpeg -i input.flv output.mp4`, then the array will be `{"ffmpeg", "-i", "input.flv", "output.mp4"}`

Comment: so what I did was added : String[] command = {"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffplay.exe", "ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555"}; and it return me value 0. But still I cannot open the ffplay. No error at all.

Comment: I wanted to get into ffplay program and execute command of "ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555". How could that be done? What I did is correct?

Comment: @DennisQT try the edited code for checking the `inputstream` as well for output

Comment: thanks ! I did copied your code and tested successfully. It returns me value 0 again. But no output for me. I suggest ffplay will only executable in windows cmd. How could I use cmd to do that ? Any idea?

Comment: @DennisQT have you tried executing the command yourself in cmd, & tested for its functionality ? I am not asking about the code here, but directly the ffplay command in cmd?

Comment: Yes I did tested out in windows cmd and it is working. I access into C:\\ffmpeg\\bin in cmd and then I typed "ffplay 192.168.1.1:5555". It can show me output there.

Comment: Well, the compiler throws me this error : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffplay" (in directory "C:\ffmpeg\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: try using `ffplay.exe` instead of `ffplay`

Comment: No luck @Ankit Nigam. I tried change to ffplay.exe instead of ffplay as you suggested for me. Error : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffplay.exe" (in directory "C:\ffmpeg\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @DennisQT can you confirm the file ffplay is there at this path C:\ffmpeg\bin

Comment: yes I am confirm that the file ffplay is located at that path C:\ffmpeg\bin. I did tried many times access using windows cmd.